# How come I can't manipulate the string in fscanf

Tags: arrays, c, string, scanf

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *testData;
    char gender[10] = {0};
    int age[10];
    int weight[10];
    int x = 0;

    testData = fopen("New Text Document.txt", "r");

  if(testData == NULL){
    printf("Error!");
    return (1);
}
while((fscanf(testData,"%s%s%s",gender,age,weight))!= EOF){
 printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n",gender,age,weight);
    if(gender == "M" || gender == 'M' || gender == "F"){
        printf("hi");
        }
}
fclose(testData);
return 0;
}
```

I am not sure why gender doesn't actually know its letter? I'm completely lost on this, manipulating age and weight is super easy, I just cant touch the gender. Also, if I put M == 77; it also doesn't do anything

the genders are single letter (F/M)

Comment: a string and a char are not the same, here gender should be a `char` and parse with `%c` if you prefer to keep it as a string you need to use `strcmp`. Activate the warning of your compiler will help you

Comment: What does a line of `New Text Document.txt` look like?

Comment: strcmp was the answer @Ôrel I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Getting the types right is very important. `char gender` means a single character. `char gender[10]` means an array of 10 characters: a string.

Similarly, `"M"` is a string, it's an array of a single `char` plus a null byte to indicate the end of the string: `{ 77, 0 }` `'M'` is a single `char`, the integer 77.

`gender == 'M'` compares two characters, which are just integers. It is, effectively, `gender == 77`. Not `gender[0] == 77`. `gender` is a memory address, some random integer, so it doesn't work.

`gender == "M"` also doesn't work. `==` will not compare string literals, it is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Instead you need to use the function [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp). `strcmp(gender, "M") == 0`.

Or you can switch `gender` to a single `char`, switch the `fscanf` to use `%c`, and do `gender == 'M' || gender == 'F'`.

Depends on exactly what the format is.

---

You also have a problem with `age` and `weight`. These are pointers to arrays of 10 integers, but you're using them as strings. This only works by luck. What's happened is `int age[10]` allocates 80 bytes of memory (8 byte integer * 10). When used as a `char *` (a string) with `%s` this is room for 80 characters (80 bytes / 1 byte per character). C doesn't actually care about the types, it will happily use whatever memory you give it so long as it all fits... and sometimes even if it doesn't.

We can see this by printing out `age` as an integer after reading "23" (after initializing it with `int age[10] = {0};` to avoid reading garbage).

```
printf("Ints %d %d %d\n", age[0], age[1], age[2]);  // 13106 0 0
```

Why 13106? That is (in hex) 32 for '2', 33 for '3', and 0 for a null byte. This is a [little-endian machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Hardware), so it's going to read it in reverse: 003332 which, in decimal, is 13106.

What you should do is `int age`, use the `%d` format, and pass it in as a pointer.

---

Putting it all together...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *testData;
    // { 0 } is more simply written as an empty string.
    char gender[10] = "":
    int age;
    int weight;

    testData = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if(testData == NULL){
        printf("Error!");
        return (1);
    }

    // fscanf takes pointers. gender is already a pointer. age and weight are not and
    // need the & operator to take their address.
    while( (fscanf(testData, "%s%d%d", gender, &age, &weight)) != EOF){
        printf("%s\n%d\n%d\n", gender, age, weight);

        // Compare strings with strcmp
        if(strcmp(gender, "M") == 0 || strcmp(gender, "F") == 0) {
            printf("hi");
        }
    }

    fclose(testData);
    return 0;
}
```